# Scala equivalent to Haskell's transpose

Tags: scala

If to exactly line-by-line translate this form of Haskell's transpose function to Scala, what it would be?

```
Haskell's transpose:
tr               :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
tr []             = []
tr ([]   : xss)   = tr xss
tr ((x:xs) : xss) = (x : map head xss) : tr (xs : map tail xss)
```

My attempt for Scala does not work:

```
def scalaTranspose(m: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = m match {
case Nil => Nil
case Nil::xss => scalaTranspose(xss)
case (x::xs)::xss => (x:: map head xss) :: scalaTranspose(xs :: map tail xss)
}
```

After struggling with translating map function, this as a last line also doesn't work:

```
case (x::xs)::xss => (x:: xss.map(head xss)) :: scalaTranspose(xs :: xss.map(tail xss))
```

Comment: `f x` is not valid function application syntax in Scala; it's `f(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala is a bit different from haskell, and the pattern matching here is also a bit lacking compared to haskell. Also, since Scala has a mix of ObjectOriented components, `head` and `tail` are `methods` defined on `List` `objects` and not pure `functions`. You will have to replace `map head xss` by scala equivalent `xss.map(_.head)`.

```
def scalaTranspose(m: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = m match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case Nil :: xss => scalaTranspose(xss)
  case (x :: xs) :: xss => (x :: xss.map(_.head)) :: scalaTranspose(xs :: xss.map(_.tail))
}
```

Comment: It fails for scalaTranspose(List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5))) with a NoSuchElementException. Is this expected?

Comment: @sparkr; Yes. Both the Haskell example and the Scala built-in `transpose` method will throw an exception trying to transpose an unbalanced collection like that.

Comment: We could certainly add some logic to handle such edge cases, but is there a mathematical definition of a transpose that would determine the logic behind a transpose. We could also write transpose as a partial function!

Comment: @sparkr It is expected as `transpose` is defined for `metrices` and `List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5))` is not a `matrix`. We can add an parameter validation but that should be implicit in this case.